# Message Passing with boost::threads?

Tags: c++, boost

Does boost have some kind of way to make message passing accross multiple threads?

I'm working on a server application and I want to be able to pass on messages throughout the application in a safe way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use Boost.Asio for this purpose: run io_service in one thread, and call io_service_.post(yourFunctor) from another thread.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::thread` provides the tools you will need, and there is a sample queue implementation [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html) that should get you started.

This also gives me another opportunity to plug this book.

> C++ Concurrency in Action is a reference and guide to the new C++ 11
>   Standard for experienced C++ programmers as well as those who have
>   never written multithreaded code. This book will show you how to write
>   robust multithreaded applications in C++ while avoiding many common
>   pitfalls.

If you are using Windows Visual C++ 10 has some proprietary tools of use here in the [Concurrency Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207192%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  VC11 expands on this.

Comment: It's already published. http://www.amazon.com/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, about time too :-)

Comment: +1 for what I was looking for.  I commented in the linked post, but thought I would comment here also:  In order to make this work in C++11 with a queue of `unique_ptr`s, I added an rvalue reference overload of `push`, here (follows next comment).  Look right, and anything else needed?

Comment: void push(Data&& data)
  {
   boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
   the_queue.push(std::move(data));
   lock.unlock();
   the_condition_variable.notify_one();
  }

Comment: Forgot to mention -- In addition, move semantics need to be applied to the various `pop` methods.